# Symfony 4 demo with adminlte bootstrap thema

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I installed Symfony 4 with the demo pack. After that i added the html pages and fixed the paths to the css files etc. But after I ran php bin/console server:run I am able to see the html page but its not loading any css or js files.

In the console i see that these are not loading and giving 404 not found error. The firewall of the demo is already configured as followed in the **security.yml**

```
firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
```

But i am still not able to load the needed files. Whats going wrong ? I am stuck and do not know how to fix this issue.

Any suggestions advice is welcome....

Update with error:

> GET
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/build/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css
>   net::ERR_ABORTED login:14 GET
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED login:17 GET
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css
>   net::ERR_ABORTED login:20 GET
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css
>   net::ERR_ABORTED login:22 GET
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/plugins/iCheck/square/blue.css
>   net::ERR_ABORTED login:87 GET
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
>   net::ERR_ABORTED login:89 GET
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
>   net::ERR_ABORTED login:91 GET
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js 404 (Not
>   Found)

Comment: Where did you place the css and js files? how are you loading them (which path do you use)?

Comment: @JimL after the demo is installed there are few maps and i put it in the /templates map.

Comment: the templates dir are for twig template files. Please have a look at this blog post going through the directory structure http://fabien.potencier.org/symfony4-directory-structure.html

Comment: @JimL Thanks for the link but did not find anything / did not understand how to use it for css/jss etc how the structure is exactly

Comment: `Web files under public/`

Comment: @JimL Still having the same issues.

Comment: You shouldn't include `/public` in the asset urls. The public folder is what is being served as the http/www docs folder so public/index.php to the outside world (users accessing the web server) is just index.php

Comment: @JimL It worked thanks alot. There are still layout issues but the most is fixed. Great help :)